# Two taps needed to switch between TextInputs (should switch with one tap)

Tags: react-native

In React Native (both iOS and Android), switching between text input elements require two taps (one to lose focus, one to gain focus). Is there a way this can be changed so that it only takes 1 click to switch between text inputs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first tap will be intercepted by the surrounding container (ie. ScrollView). `keyboardShouldPersistTaps` fixes this, see how it's used in the
[React Native UI Explorer](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Examples/UIExplorer/UIExplorerExampleList.js#L74).